# Allow to move elements only between lists in Sortable No Jquery without sorting

Tags: javascript

Sortable No Jquery supports multiple lists using the `group` attribute.

I want to allow users to move elements between different lists but not to reorder the elements within the list itself.

I tried using `pull` and `put` functions for the `group` option but without success.

I used the `sort: false` option which helps and almost reach the goal but when moving an item between two lists the users are still able to sort it.

I prepared a JSBin with three list to make some tests but I really couldn't figure out if is possible or not.

http://jsbin.com/cuneku/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

you should use sort false. so you cant sort with in same group. Do you want  like this?

```
        Sortable.create(list1, {
          animation: 100,
          group: 'same',
           sort: false,  
        });

        Sortable.create(list2, {
          animation: 100,
          group: 'same',
          sort: false,  
        });



        Sortable.create(list3, {
          animation: 150, // ms, animation speed moving items when sorting, `0` — without animation
          group: "same",
          sort: false,
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

added the data-id to control sort order of all items.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


    <!-- Latest Sortable -->
    <script src="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/Sortable.js"></script>


    <!-- HTML -->
    <ul id="list1" class="list-group">
    <li data-id="0" class="list-group-item">Element in group 1</li>
    </ul>


    <ul id="list2" class="list-group">
    <li data-id="1" class="list-group-item">This is <a href="http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/">Sortable</a></li>
    <li data-id="2" class="list-group-item">It works with Bootstrap...</li>
    <li data-id="3" class="list-group-item">...out of the box.</li>
    <li data-id="4" class="list-group-item">It has support for touch devices.</li>
    <li data-id="5" class="list-group-item">Just drag some elements around.</li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="list3" class="list-group">
    <li data-id="6" class="list-group-item">Element in group 3</li>
    </ul>
```

Then used the onAdd event handler to resort back into the right order.

```
    Sortable.create(list1, {
      animation: 100,
      group: 'same',
      sort: false,
      onAdd: function (evt){onadditem(evt, this);}
    });

    Sortable.create(list2, {
      animation: 100,
      group: 'same',
      sort: false,
      onAdd: function (evt){onadditem(evt, this);}
    });

    Sortable.create(list3, {
      animation: 100,
      group: 'same',
      sort: false,
      onAdd: function (evt){onadditem(evt, this);}
    });

    // common sorting function
    function onadditem(evt, me) {
      var order = me.toArray();
       order.sort();
       me.sort(order); // apply
    }
```